# android materialDialog not dismissed

Tags: android, material-design

```
package util;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;

import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog;
import com.ticket.book.AppController;

public class PDialog extends AppController {

    static  MaterialDialog.Builder mDialog = null;

    public static  void show(Context csContext) {

        mDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(csContext);
               // .title(R.string.progress_dialog)
        mDialog.content(string.app_alert_loading)
               .progress(true, 1)
               .show();
    }


    public static  void hide() {

        if(mDialog!=null){

            mDialog.dismiss(); // dismiss is not available
        }
    }
}
```

in main acvitity

I call  PDialog.show(); - now showed the progress dialog

When I call Dialog.hide() - but progress dialog not dismissed

I am using this https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs library. I created

```
mDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(csContext);
               // .title(R.string.progress_dialog)
        mDialog.content(string.app_alert_loading)
               .progress(true, 1)
               .show();
```

My problem is I am not unable to dismiss this dialog.

Thanks,

Comment: Post your full code of creating and dissmising the dialog.

Comment: I posted an answer. Test it and accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Did you solved your problem? Is my answer is helpful for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should save MaterialDialog object, not the MaterialDialog.Builder object.

```
private static MaterialDialog progressDialog;

public static void show(Context csContext) {
       progressDialog= new MaterialDialog.Builder(csContext)
            .content(string.app_alert_loading)
            .progress(true, 1)
            .build();
       progressDialog.show();
}

public static void dissmissProgressDialog() {
    if(progressDialog!=null){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: HI, its not work for me. Please see the screen shots

Comment: @Sarathi Manivel its because you didnt copy paste my code. You have `;` at the end of the line. Just copy and paste my code.